# Object not getting assigned.

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an asp.net MVC project and have the following code in my view model

```
public Division ToDivision()
        {
            Division d = new Division();
            Name = this.Name;
            Active = this.Active;
            return d;
        }
```

Then, in my controller, I have the following method:

```
public ActionResult Create(DivisionViewModel divisionViewModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Division division;
                division = divisionViewModel.ToDivision();
                _divisionService.Create(division);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(divisionViewModel);
        }
```

Division is not getting assigned.  Why is this? I have a feeling it's something very simple that I'm just not seeing

Comment: What you mean "Division is not getting assigned"  ? Do you have a compile time error in the assignment line ? If not, what specifically is the problem ?

Comment: What does this line do, `_divisionService.Create(division);`? Could you elaborate on the `.Create` method?

Comment: What do you mean by "Not getting assigned". Do you mean the `Name` and `Active` values are not being assigned? Because if so, you never set them. You need to do `d.Name = this.Name,`

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify.  I can step through the code, and the Name is assigned a value in the ToDivision function, but in the controller the division variable has a null value for name.

Comment: `Name = this.Name;` => this assigns internal `Name` but not `d.Name`. Since you're returning `d`, the `d.Name` actually has null value.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  I've been looking at the screen for way too long.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think, you are trying to use objectinitializer but mistakenly, you are just assinging value to property only. like `Division d = new Division(){
            Name = this.Name,
            Active = this.Active}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your function `ToDivision`, `Name = this.Name` doesn't do anything because they are the same value.  You need to do `d.Name = this.Name`. Similarly for `Active`. Try:

```
public Division ToDivision()
{
    Division d = new Division();
    d.Name = this.Name;
    d.Active = this.Active;
    return d;
}
```

Comment: You forgot the `d.Name` and `d.Active` in the code block (what you have shown is identical to OP's code)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes. As I wrote: *In the following function...*

Comment: Not much point repeating OP's code - better to show the correct code :)

Answer (score 3):

From your code example seems that you want to use object initialization in a method with property member assignment, but assigned to the `Name` member instead of `d.Name`. Try using the following initializer:

```
public Division ToDivision()
{
    Division d = new Division()
    {
        Name = this.Name;
        Active = this.Active;
    }
    return d;
}
```